# my app.yaml on google cloud is not working well

Tags: javascript, php, google-cloud-platform

I am doing a webpage, this webpage has a form on php, with a script js that get the value of the form and then it send it to other php, I am doing this on google cloud

**the app.yaml is**

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /index\.html
  script: index.php

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /server/(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /img
  static_dir: img
```

**The index, css, js and img is working fine but serve php script is not working**

**my form**

```
<form method="post" id="formdata" action="">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="user">User</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="User"name="User" aria-describedby="UserHelp" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Password1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
           <button id="botonEnviar"type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

**my script js**

`$("#botonEnviar").click( function() {alert("0");     
            if(validaForm()){                       
                **$.post("server/buscarUsuario.php",$("#formdata").serialize(),function(res)**{
                    //$("#formulario").fadeOut("slow");   
                    if(res == 1){alert("3"); 
                        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";     .
                    } else {
                        if(res == 99){alert("4"); 
                        $("#fracaso").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");   
                        }  
                    }
                });
            }
        });`

I want to send the post to buscarUsuario.php that it is on the server folder, but the web page said this
Post `https://***.com/server/buscarUsuario.php 404 ()`
I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you’ve said in the last sentence, I get the idea that you have the “buscarUsuario.php” file under a folder called “server”. If it’s the case, it should be under the root server, where your .yaml file is, as it’s written in the handler `script: \1`. In case you want the file to be in the server folder, you should have the handler as `script: /server/\1`.